# theme.xml magento 2?

Tags: magento2

what is use of theme.xml file please explain briefly in magento 2 ?

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> <body> <referenceBlock name="logo"> <arguments> <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/theme_logo.png</argument> <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">300</argument> <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">300</argument> </arguments> </referenceBlock> </body> </page>

    argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">300</argument> </arguments> </referenceBlock> </body> </page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Magento2 `theme.xml` contains basics configuration to create your theme. And the required field in this xml file is title and parent theme(the theme which you are considering as a parent, for example, `blank`,`luma`). Example of luma theme

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Magento Luma</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

Here title is theme tile which you can find it from backend > content > Design > Themes

[image]

`<parent>` is your parent theme name and `<preview_image>` contains your theme's preview image which you can find it on your theme detail page,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Declaring Theme Logo

In the Magento application, the default format and name of a logo image is logo.svg. You can use a logo file with a different name and format, but you might need to declare it. You have to create a file default.xml in your theme’s layout directory and below code if you theme_logo.png is in size of 300×300: